# Exclude WIFI from NETWORK_PROVIDER

Tags: android

Is there a way to exclude WIFI when requesting coarse location? I don't want to use GPS because of the power consumption and the longer time that it takes to aqcuire the location.

But I need to get the location only from the cell phone towers. The NETWORK_PROVIDER mode also uses WIFI (accesspoint MAC addresses) that google has on its database. I don't want to use those. Is there a way to exclude WIFI from NETWORK_PROVIDER ?

Thanks !

Comment: Is there any particular reason why?

Answer (score 2):

One way of obtaining this is to use `PASSIVE_PROVIDER`, which as stated [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#PASSIVE_PROVIDER):

> *A special location provider for receiving locations without actually initiating a location fix.*
>
> This provider can be used to passively receive location updates when
>   other applications or services request them without actually
>   requesting the locations yourself. This provider will return locations
>   generated by other providers. You can query the getProvider() method
>   to determine the origin of the location update. Requires the
>   permission ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, although if the GPS is not enabled
>   this provider might only return coarse fixes.
>
> *Constant Value: "passive"*

One certain way of obtaining what you want is the following:

```
ConnectivityManager conMan = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

State mobile = conMan.getNetworkInfo(0).getState();
State wifi = conMan.getNetworkInfo(1).getState();
```

After that, you distinguish them by:

```
if (mobile == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED || mobile == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING) {
    //mobile
} else if (wifi == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED || wifi == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING) {
    //wifi
}
```

Check, if the mobile or wifi is connected, if wifi - then use `PASSIVE_PROVIDER`, if mobile - use `NETWORK_PROVIDER`.

Cheers :)